# Find command with multiple conditions

Tags: find

I present you the following use-case:

```
[root@localCentOS71 folder]# ls -lah
total 16K
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root  4.0K Dec 22 08:52 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root  4.0K Dec 21 14:59 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root test     0 Dec 22 08:52 file
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4.0K Dec 21 14:59 hi
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     0 Dec 22 08:46 .htaccess
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   175 Dec 22 08:47 test
```

I am trying to invoke a `find` command, to perform:

- Find only regular files
- Find where owner is not root or
- Find where group is not root or
- Find where permissions are not 775 and
- Exclude .htaccess files

Current command:

`find /folder -not -user root -or -not -group test -type f \( ! -iname ".htaccess" \) -or -not -perm 775`

Desired output:

```
/folder/test
/folder/file
```

Actual output:

```
/folder
/folder/.htaccess
/folder/hi
/folder/test
/folder/file
```

Comment: `find` always finds only files. Do you mean that you want it to find only _regular_ files (as opposed to files of type _directory_ or _symlink_ or _device_...)?

Comment: yes, I meant regular files. Therefore the argument `-type f` is given.

Answer (score 4):

Beware that `-a` (implicit between two predicates if ommited) has precedence over `-o`, so you need to use parentheses:

```
find /folder ! -name .htaccess -type f \( \
   ! -user root -o ! -group test -o ! -perm 775 \)
```

Or:

```
find /folder ! -name .htaccess -type f ! \( \
   -user root -group test -perm 775 \)
```

I do the `-name` first as an optimisation as it doesn't need to do a `lstat()` on the file. Some `find` implementations do that optimisation by themselves (re-order the list of predicates internally).

Note that `-not` and `-or` are non-standard GNU extensions. `!` and `-o` are the standard equivalent.

Because of the precedence rules, your

```
find /folder -not -user root -or -not -group test -type f \( 
  ! -iname ".htaccess" \) -or -not -perm 775
```

Is actually interpreted as:

```
find /folder \( -not -user root \) -or \
             \( -not -group test -a \
                -type f -a \
               \( ! -iname ".htaccess" \) \
             \) -or \
             \( -not -perm 775 \)
```

Comment: Yes, this works. #win